# Reflect on a dynamic type to tell if it was a dynamic type, to begin with

Tags: c#, reflection, dynamic, c#-4.0

Is there a way that one can tell if the type that an object was assigned to, was a dynamic type?

For example:

```
dynamic foo = GetCat();

Console.WriteLine( (foo is Cat).ToString() ); // will print True because
// at the execution time, foo will have assumed the Cat type. However, is
// there a mechanism by which I can reflect on foo and say, "This guy was assigned
// a dynamic type, to begin with."?
```

Comment: I think that's not possible, but since I'm not completely sure, I'll just wait and see what answers come in. ;)

Comment: Out of curiosity, why do you want to know?

Comment: Hi Eric, I thought your comment was directed at Lucero. But I suspect now that it was directed towards my original question. I've sent you a private email at your official email address with the answer to your question.

Comment: See this too: [is-there-a-way-to-test-if-a-variable-is-dynamic](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19785655/is-there-a-way-to-test-if-a-variable-is-dynamic)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there a way that one can tell if the type that an object was assigned to was a dynamic type?

Nope, not if foo is a local variable.

"dynamic" is a compile-time feature. It's just a hint to the compiler that means "don't bother to try to do type analysis at compile time on this expression; instead, generate code that invokes a special version of the compiler at runtime".

At runtime, the local variable foo is just a local variable of type object, and the contents of the local variable are a reference to a Cat.  The fact that the compiler knew that the author of the code wanted to avoid type analysis on foo at compile time has been lost.

It *is* possible to figure out whether a method that returns object is actually returning dynamic, by examining the compiler-generated attributes on the method using reflection.

Comment: What is the attribute on methods returning a dynamic type?  I see "DynamicAttribute" on a field or property with a dynamic type, but this attribute does not appear on a method returning 'dynamic' when I reflect on it (at least, not in my test case)??

Comment: An example of this not working for methods is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8439786/how-do-you-determine-if-a-method-returns-a-dynamic-type-when-using-reflection