# Casting Dynamic Object and Passing Into UnitOfWork and Repository Pattern. Throws Exception

Tags: c#, repository-pattern, unit-of-work, expandoobject, dynamicobject

This is a very specific problem.  Not quite sure how to even word it.  Basically I am implementing the unit of work and repository pattern, I have a dynamic object that I convert to an int, but if I use `var` it will throw an exception when trying to call the method.

I tried to remove all the trivial variables to this problem that I can.  For some reason I only see it happen with these two design patterns. The exception I get is `Additional information: 'BlackMagic.ITacoRepo' does not contain a definition for 'DoStuff'`

Here is the code:

```
class BlackMagic
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        dynamic obj = new ExpandoObject();
        obj.I = 69;

        UnitOfWork uow = new UnitOfWork();

        int i1 = Convert.ToInt32(obj.I);
        var i2 = Convert.ToInt32(obj.I);

        if(i1.Equals(i2))
        {
            uow.TacoRepo.DoStuff(i1); // Works fine
            uow.TacoRepo.DoStuff(i2); // Throws Exception
        }
    }
}

class UnitOfWork
{
    public ITacoRepo TacoRepo { get; set; }

    public UnitOfWork()
    {
        TacoRepo = new TacoRepo();
    }
}

class Repo<T> : IRepo<T> where T : class
{
    public void DoStuff(int i)
    {
    }
}

interface IRepo<T> where T : class
{
    void DoStuff(int i);
}

class TacoRepo : Repo<Taco>, ITacoRepo
{
}

interface ITacoRepo : IRepo<Taco>
{
}

class Taco
{
}
```

**EDIT:** The main question I am trying to find an answer for, is why would the exception get thrown by calling `DoStuff` inside the unit of work (while using the repo) but not get thrown if DoStuff existed in the `BlackMagic` class.

Comment: Can you toss in a breakpoint before `DoStuff` is called and see what actual runtime type `i2` is?

Comment: @EdPlunkett it tells me it is an Int32

Comment: Yep, just tried it. The value in `i2` is `System.Int32`. But I think it's behaving as if `i2` is a dynamic reference to something else: If you pass a `dynamic` argument to a method, overload resolution is done at runtime. `uow.TacoRepo.DoStuff((int)i2);` works fine .

Comment: This is happening because the runtime uses reflection in order to attempt to determine the type of `i2`. However, since `i2` came from a `ExpandoObject` it's declaring and reflected type are null, and as a result it does not match the `int` requirement of `DoStuff`. Strange indeed, perhaps you should just avoid using dynamic here in that fashion.

Comment: Yeah, what he said!

Comment: @TravisJ I gotcha.  So one thing that I'm curious about.  In the actual code that this problem comes from, I actually using the Newtonsoft Json library to convert a Json string to a dynamic object like: `dynamic obj = JObject.Parse(strJson)` so is it still the same reason for not working?

Comment: To be honest, it is an interesting phenomenon and the reason I only posted that as a comment was in the hopes of someone who could expand on it or at least explain perhaps why the runtime didn't know that Convert.ToInt was an int type when using `var` there. As for your question with regards to parsing a json string into a dynamic object, I think that requires the same type of reflection as a model binder, and with dynamic that option doesn't seem to exist. Unsure though off the top of my head what the connection between this example shown and your issue with parse is wrt dynamic.

Comment: @TravisJ What is interesting too that I just noticed, is hovering over i2 in the debugger it says that it is a dynamic object

Comment: `var i2 = Int32.Parse(obj.I.ToString())` throws the same exception. `var i2 = Int32.Parse($"{obj.I}");` doesn't. @TravisJ the declaring and reflected types of `i1` are null as well here.

Comment: [Hmmmm.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2883781/424129)

Comment: @EdPlunkett yeah, so like I said to Travis, in your example, if you hover over your former example, you'll see the debugger will say it is a dynamic object. If you hover over the latter it says it is an int.  But at runtime GetType says they are both Int32... which is odd to me

Comment: If I understand [Eric Lippert in my link above](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2883781/424129), it's all the compiler messing with you. `GetType()` is runtime. By the compiler's logic, `var i2` means you're happy for `i2` to be dynamic. What's weirding me is that according to my understanding of `dynamic` and overload resolution, it ought to be happy with `DoStuff(int)` -- so clearly my "understanding" isn't.

Comment: @EdPlunkett I dont have a super high level of understanding of the compiler.  But wouldn't when you have `var i2` assigned the `Convert.ToInt32()` method, wouldn't that tell the compiler that `i2` will be an `int`?

Comment: I'd have forgiven you for expecting it to take the hint there, yeah. I'm dumbfounded myself. But it wants an explicit cast: `var i2 = (int)Convert.ToInt32(obj.I);` makes i2 non-dynamic. In fact, `var i2 = (int)obj.I;` makes i2 non-dynamic. Maybe more gobsmacked than dumbfounded, if you want to be pedantic.

Comment: Here's another thing: If I give `UnitOfWork` a method `public void Foo(int x) { }`, I can call `uow.Foo(i2)` with dynamic `i2`. I don't understand how that method differs from `ITacoRepo.DoStuff(int)`.

Comment: @EdPlunkett When I do this: `var i2 = Convert.ToInt32((object)obj.I);` no more exception.  I guess I don't fully understand why the parameters you pass in have any effect on what is returned.  I mean `Convert.ToInt32` always returns an `int` so I don't understand why it is dynamic instead

Comment: @EdPlunkett Yeah it is really weird because I tested this problem in many different ways.  But it only seemed to happen when I used the unit of work and repository pattern.  I was not able to replicate it in any other way.

Comment: While I am not sure of the why, I can at least tell you that the runtime binder is the who in the type determinations.

Comment: My impression is the compiler is looking at the parameter to that particular call to `Convert.ToInt32()`, and saying "OK, this is a dynamic parameter. And we're assigning the Int32 value this call returns to something declared `var`, so but a dynamic came in, so we'll go and make that `var` `dynamic` too." It's changing the meaning of that `var` declaration. The return value from `Convert.ToInt32()` isn't changing -- the compiler is changing what happens to it after return. Dump the MSIL and see what you get.

Comment: @EdPlunkett I actually don't have any tools on this machine right now to get it

Comment: One thing I do want to note though, if I take DoStuff out of the Repo, and drop it into the BlackMagic class, the problem doesn't happen anymore.  But for some reason using these design patterns, it throws the exception.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does a method invocation expression have type dynamic even when there is only one possible return type?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9382130/why-does-a-method-invocation-expression-have-type-dynamic-even-when-there-is-onl)

Comment: So I voted to close this as a duplicate. Let me explain why. The reason that `int` is not being used as the type is because the rule for using implicit conversion on the return type of the method call (in this case ToInt) has several conditions, one of which is violated in this situation, notably that "The primary-expression has compile-time type dynamic." As a result the implicit conversion is not used, and the best accessible type (object) is used as a result. There is no definition for DoStuff(object) and as a result the runtime exception occurs.

Comment: @TravisJ But why is i2 an acceptable argument for other methods that take int? (Never mind, just saw Sunshine's answer. But this is not a dupe of that other question -- it's a combination of that one, and the surprising runtime binding behavior)

Comment: @TravisJ I agree with Ed on this.  You make a good point about the dynamic object conversion, but the error doesn't get thrown if I take `DoStuff` out of the Repo and put it in the main `BlackMagic' class then pass i2 in

Comment: @TravisJ I do agree that the link you posted does answer our discussion about the dynamic object conversion.  But I am not sure if it completely answers the main question of: Why is the exception thrown.  I think that Sunshine's answer is on the right path, but not sure if it completely answers it.

Comment: it's weird but can you check what is the type of i2 at runtime if it turn out to be anything other than Int32 then that's the reason - note that the compiler doesn't check dynamic type at compile time

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is one of the bugs I reported to Microsoft more than 5 years ago, soon after the `dynamic` was introduced. As far as I know, it is considered of a very low priority on their list, and might never be fixed.

Here are simple repro steps:

```
using System.Collections;

class C
{
    static void Main()
    {
        object[] array = { };
        IList list = new ArrayList();
        list.CopyTo(array, 0); // Works okay
        dynamic index = 0;
        list.CopyTo(array, index); // Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException: 'System.Collections.IList' does not contain a definition for 'CopyTo'
    }
}
```

Here is an explanation of the problem. When a function member (a  method or an indexer) is invoked on an expression whose static type is an interface type, and at least one of the arguments to the invocation is of the type `dynamic` (which means the complete member lookup -- type inference -- overload resolution process is postponed until runtime, and becomes a responsibility of the runtime binder rather than the compiler; only a partial set of checks is performed by the compiler based on incomplete type information), and the member being invoked is inherited by the interface from one of its base interfaces (rather than declared in the interface itself), then the runtime binder fails to properly traverse the tree of the base interfaces to find the inherited member, and throws an exception at runtime, reporting that the required member is not found. Note that it is only the runtime binder's fault -- the compiler properly accepted the invocation (but would reject it, if, for example, you made a typo in the method name).

A possible workaround: cast the expression you invoke a member on to the base interface that actually declares the member you are trying to invoke. For example, the program from the repro steps above could be fixed as follows:

```
using System.Collections;

class C
{
    static void Main()
    {
        object[] array = { };
        IList list = new ArrayList();
        list.CopyTo(array, 0); // Works okay
        dynamic index = 0;
        ((ICollection) list).CopyTo(array, index); // Works okay
    }
}
```

Or, if possible, get rid of the dynamic dispatch completely by casting the argument(s) of type `dynamic` to the type specified in the invoked member's signature.

```
using System.Collections;

class C
{
    static void Main()
    {
        object[] array = { };
        IList list = new ArrayList();
        list.CopyTo(array, 0); // Works okay
        dynamic index = 0;
        list.CopyTo(array, (int) index); // Works okay
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, both workarounds might be not helpful if you really want overload resolution to happen at runtime, and among the possible candidates there are both members declared by the interface, and members inherited by it. You would probably need to invent some ad hoc solution in that case, or significantly refactor your program.

Comment: So essentially you're saying, that since the interface `ITacoRepo` doesn't explicitly implement the interface `IRepo<Taco>`'s `DoStuff` method, it doesn't know where else to look?  That it is simply just looking at `ITacoRepo`?  So technically a problem in interfaces implementing interfaces when passing dynamics in?

Comment: Interfaces cannot implement other interfaces, they can only inherit from them. They can re-declare inherited abstract members, but that does not constitute implementations. Of course, a variable of an interface type at runtime (if not null) will contain a reference to an object of some concrete type that has implementations of all members of the interface, both declared (or re-declared) in it, and inherited. But overload resolution must occur based on the statically known type of the receiver, that is, on the interface type. The runtime binder fails to properly collect inherited candidates.

Comment: At runtime, though, when you call `GetType` on `i2`, it tells you that it is an `Int32`.  Why would it still cause the same problem?  I see why it would if you kept it as a `dynamic`, but if the problem happens at runtime, I don't understand why it wouldnt accept an `int`

Comment: The variable `i2` is declared as `var` that means its compile-time type is  inferred from its initializer. Its initializer contains a sub-expression `obj` of type `dynamic`, so the type of the initializer is also `dynamic`, and so is the type of `i2` (exactly as if you explicitly declared it as `dynamic`). It means that any method invocation using `i2` as an argument has to be resolved dynamically at runtime, using the runtime type of the object it refers to for applicability checks and overload resolution. The bug in the runtime binder prevents it from finding an applicable inherited method.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the RuntimeBinder doesn't traverse the inheritance hierarchy so it only looks in the immediate interface `ITacoRepo` for a definition of DoStuff.

If you make the the `UnitOfWork` use `IRepo<Taco>` instead of `ITacoRepo`, it is able to find the method definition.

Comment: Why would this be true of the `var` i2 and not of the `int` i1?

Comment: @TravisJ Because RuntimeBinder isn't involved in the call with i1. That's all compile time.

Comment: So then why if I created a local `IRepo<Taco> r = new TacoRepo()` and then call `r.DoStuff(i2)` would I not get the error?

Comment: @THEStephenStanton What happens if you define `r` as `ITacoRepo`, like the definition in `UnitOfWork`? I think the problem is the type you're using, not where the variable is.

Comment: @KendallFrey So you raise an interesting point that I tried (if I understand you right).  If I have just have `TacoRepo` and `ITacoRepo`, and I move the signature `DoStuff` to `ITacoRepo`, then implement it in 'TacoRepo', and just do 'ITacoRepo r = new TacoRepo()' then do 'r.DoStuff(i2)', there is no exception.  Which is why it is so weird that it only happens when I use this design pattern